# Uncaught ReferenceError: particlesJS is not defined at app.js:2

Tags: javascript

Подключил CDN particles.js а также поставил defer при загрузке но ошибка все равно есть
Вот код app.js :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ancho = $(window).width();

  if (ancho > 600) {
    /* particlesJS('dom-id', params);
    /* @dom-id : set the html tag id [string, optional, default value : particles-js]
    /* @params: set the params [object, optional, default values : check particles.js] */

    /* config dom id (optional) + config particles params */
    particlesJS('particles-js', {
      particles: {
        color: '#000',
        color_random: false,
        shape: 'circle', // "circle", "edge" or "triangle"
        opacity: {
          opacity: 1,
          anim: {
            enable: true,
            speed: 1.5,
            opacity_min: 0,
            sync: false
          }
        },
        size: 4,
        size_random: true,
        nb: 150,
        line_linked: {
          enable_auto: true,
          distance: 100,
          color: '#fff',
          opacity: 1,
          width: 1,
          condensed_mode: {
            enable: false,
            rotateX: 600,
            rotateY: 600
          }
        },
        anim: {
          enable: true,
          speed: 1
        }
      },
      interactivity: {
        enable: true,
        mouse: {
          distance: 300
        },
        detect_on: 'canvas', // "canvas" or "window"
        mode: 'grab', // "grab" of false
        line_linked: {
          opacity: .5
        },
        events: {
          onclick: {
            enable: true,
            mode: 'push', // "push" or "remove"
            nb: 4
          },
          onresize: {
            enable: true,
            mode: 'out', // "out" or "bounce"
            density_auto: false,
            density_area: 800 // nb_particles = particles.nb * (canvas width *  canvas height / 1000) / density_area
          }
        }
      },
      /* Retina Display Support */
      retina_detect: true
    });
  }

});

/* -----------------------------------------------
/* Author : Natalio Rabasco
/* ----------------------------------------------- */

function launchParticlesJS(tag_id, params) {

  var canvas_el = document.querySelector('#' + tag_id + ' > canvas');

  /* particles.js variables with default values */
  pJS = {
    canvas: {
      el: canvas_el,
      w: canvas_el.offsetWidth,
      h: canvas_el.offsetHeight
    },
    particles: {
      color: '#fff',
      color_random: false,
      shape: 'circle', // "circle", "edge" or "triangle"
      opacity: {
        opacity: 1,
        anim: {
          enable: false,
          speed: 2,
          opacity_min: 0,
          sync: false
        }
      },
      size: 2.5,
      size_random: true,
      nb: 200,
      line_linked: {
        enable_auto: true,
        distance: 100,
        color: '#fff',
        opacity: 1,
        width: 1,
        condensed_mode: {
          enable: false,
          rotateX: 3000,
          rotateY: 3000
        }
      },
      anim: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 2
      },
      array: []
    },
    interactivity: {
      enable: true,
      mouse: {
        distance: 100
      },
      detect_on: 'canvas',
      mode: 'grab',
      line_linked: {
        opacity: 1
      },
      events: {
        onclick: {
          enable: true,
          mode: 'push',
          nb: 4
        },
        onresize: {
          enable: true,
          mode: 'out', // "out" or "bounce"
          density_auto: false,
          density_area: 800 // nb_particles = particles.nb * (canvas width *  canvas height / 1000) / density_area
        }
      }
    },
    retina_detect: false,
    fn: {
      vendors: {
        interactivity: {}
      }
    }
  };

  /* params settings */
  if (params) {
    if (params.particles) {
      var paramsForParticles = params.particles;
      if (paramsForParticles.color) pJS.particles.color = paramsForParticles.color;
      if (paramsForParticles.color_random) pJS.particles.color_random = paramsForParticles.color_random;
      if (paramsForParticles.shape) pJS.particles.shape = paramsForParticles.shape;
      if (paramsForParticles.opacity) {
        var paramsForOpacity = paramsForParticles.opacity;
        if (typeof paramsForOpacity == 'object') pJS.particles.opacity.opacity = paramsForOpacity.opacity;
        else pJS.particles.opacity.opacity = paramsForOpacity;
        if (paramsForOpacity.anim) {
          var paramsForOpacityAnim = paramsForOpacity.anim;
          if (paramsForOpacityAnim.enable == false || paramsForOpacityAnim.enable) pJS.particles.opacity.anim.enable = paramsForOpacityAnim.enable;
          if (paramsForOpacityAnim.speed) pJS.particles.opacity.anim.speed = paramsForOpacityAnim.speed;
          if (paramsForOpacityAnim.opacity_min) pJS.particles.opacity.anim.opacity_min = paramsForOpacityAnim.opacity_min;
          if (paramsForOpacityAnim.sync == false || paramsForOpacityAnim.sync) pJS.particles.opacity.anim.sync = paramsForOpacityAnim.sync;
        }
      }
      if (paramsForParticles.size) pJS.particles.size = paramsForParticles.size;
      if (paramsForParticles.size_random == false) pJS.particles.size_random = paramsForParticles.size_random;
      if (paramsForParticles.nb) pJS.particles.nb = paramsForParticles.nb;
      if (paramsForParticles.line_linked) {
        var paramsForLineLinked = paramsForParticles.line_linked;
        if (paramsForLineLinked.enable_auto == false) pJS.particles.line_linked.enable_auto = paramsForLineLinked.enable_auto;
        if (paramsForLineLinked.distance) pJS.particles.line_linked.distance = paramsForLineLinked.distance;
        if (paramsForLineLinked.color) pJS.particles.line_linked.color = paramsForLineLinked.color;
        if (paramsForLineLinked.opacity) pJS.particles.line_linked.opacity = paramsForLineLinked.opacity;
        if (paramsForLineLinked.width) pJS.particles.line_linked.width = paramsForLineLinked.width;
        if (paramsForLineLinked.condensed_mode) {
          var paramsForCondensedMode = paramsForLineLinked.condensed_mode;
          if (paramsForCondensedMode.enable == false) pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.enable = paramsForCondensedMode.enable;
          if (paramsForCondensedMode.rotateX) pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateX = paramsForCondensedMode.rotateX;
          if (paramsForCondensedMode.rotateY) pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateY = paramsForCondensedMode.rotateY;
        }
      }
      if (paramsForParticles.anim) {
        var paramsForAnim = paramsForParticles.anim;
        if (paramsForAnim.enable == false) pJS.particles.anim.enable = paramsForAnim.enable;
        if (paramsForAnim.speed) pJS.particles.anim.speed = paramsForAnim.speed;
      }
    }
    if (params.interactivity) {
      var paramsForInteractivity = params.interactivity;
      if (paramsForInteractivity.enable == false) pJS.interactivity.enable = paramsForInteractivity.enable;
      if (paramsForInteractivity.mouse) {
        if (paramsForInteractivity.mouse.distance) pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance = paramsForInteractivity.mouse.distance;
      }
      if (paramsForInteractivity.detect_on) pJS.interactivity.detect_on = paramsForInteractivity.detect_on;
      if (paramsForInteractivity.mode == false || paramsForInteractivity.mode) pJS.interactivity.mode = paramsForInteractivity.mode;
      if (paramsForInteractivity.line_linked) {
        if (paramsForInteractivity.line_linked.opacity) pJS.interactivity.line_linked.opacity = paramsForInteractivity.line_linked.opacity;
      }
      if (paramsForInteractivity.events) {
        var paramsForEvents = paramsForInteractivity.events;
        if (paramsForEvents.onclick) {
          var paramsForOnclick = paramsForEvents.onclick;
          if (paramsForOnclick.enable == false) pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.enable = false;
          if (paramsForOnclick.mode != 'push') pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.mode = paramsForOnclick.mode;
          if (paramsForOnclick.nb) pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.nb = paramsForOnclick.nb;
        }
        if (paramsForEvents.onresize) {
          var paramsForOnresize = paramsForEvents.onresize;
          if (paramsForOnresize.enable == false) pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.enable = false;
          if (paramsForOnresize.mode) pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.mode = paramsForOnresize.mode;
          if (paramsForOnresize.density_auto == false || paramsForOnresize.density_auto) pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.density_auto = paramsForOnresize.density_auto;
          if (paramsForOnresize.density_area) pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.density_area = paramsForOnresize.density_area;
        }
      }
    }
    pJS.retina_detect = params.retina_detect;
  }

  /* convert hex colors to rgb */
  pJS.particles.color_rgb = hexToRgb(pJS.particles.color);
  pJS.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line = hexToRgb(pJS.particles.line_linked.color);

  /* detect retina */
  if (pJS.retina_detect && window.devicePixelRatio > 1) {
    pJS.retina = true;

    pJS.canvas.pxratio = window.devicePixelRatio
    pJS.canvas.w = pJS.canvas.el.offsetWidth * pJS.canvas.pxratio;
    pJS.canvas.h = pJS.canvas.el.offsetHeight * pJS.canvas.pxratio;
    pJS.particles.anim.speed = pJS.particles.anim.speed * pJS.canvas.pxratio;
    pJS.particles.line_linked.distance = pJS.particles.line_linked.distance * pJS.canvas.pxratio;
    pJS.particles.line_linked.width = pJS.particles.line_linked.width * pJS.canvas.pxratio;
    pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance = pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance * pJS.canvas.pxratio;
  }


  /* ---------- CANVAS functions ------------ */

  pJS.fn.canvasInit = function() {
    pJS.canvas.ctx = pJS.canvas.el.getContext('2d');
  };

  pJS.fn.canvasSize = function() {

    pJS.canvas.el.width = pJS.canvas.w;
    pJS.canvas.el.height = pJS.canvas.h;

    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {

      if (pJS && pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.enable) {

        pJS.canvas.w = pJS.canvas.el.offsetWidth;
        pJS.canvas.h = pJS.canvas.el.offsetHeight;

        /* resize canvas */
        if (pJS.retina) {
          pJS.canvas.w *= pJS.canvas.pxratio;
          pJS.canvas.h *= pJS.canvas.pxratio;
        }

        pJS.canvas.el.width = pJS.canvas.w;
        pJS.canvas.el.height = pJS.canvas.h;

        /* repaint canvas */
        pJS.fn.canvasPaint();
        if (!pJS.particles.anim.enable) {
          pJS.fn.particlesRemove();
          pJS.fn.canvasRemove();
          launchParticles();
        }

        /* density particles enabled */
        pJS.fn.densityAuto();

      }

    });

  };

  pJS.fn.densityAuto = function() {
    if (pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.density_auto) {

      /* calc area */
      var area = pJS.canvas.el.width * pJS.canvas.el.height / 1000;
      if (pJS.retina) {
        area = area / (pJS.canvas.pxratio * 2);
      }

      /* calc number of particles based on density area */
      var nb_particles = area * pJS.particles.nb / pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.density_area;

      /* show nb_particles (add or remove X particles) */
      var missing_particles = pJS.particles.array.length - nb_particles;
      if (missing_particles < 0) {
        pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.pushParticles(Math.abs(missing_particles));
      } else {
        pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.removeParticles(missing_particles);
      }

    }
  };

  pJS.fn.canvasPaint = function() {
    pJS.canvas.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, pJS.canvas.w, pJS.canvas.h);
  };

  pJS.fn.canvasRemove = function() {
    pJS.canvas.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, pJS.canvas.w, pJS.canvas.h);
  }


  /* --------- PARTICLES functions ----------- */

  pJS.fn.particle = function(color, opacity, position) {

    /* position */
    this.x = position ? position.x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w;
    this.y = position ? position.y : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.h;

    /* size */
    this.radius = (pJS.particles.size_random ? Math.random() : 1) * pJS.particles.size;
    if (pJS.retina) this.radius *= pJS.canvas.pxratio;

    /* color */
    if (pJS.particles.color_random) {
      this.color = {
        r: (Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1)) + 0),
        g: (Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1)) + 0),
        b: (Math.floor(Math.random() * (255 - 0 + 1)) + 0)
      }
    } else {
      this.color = color;
    }

    /* opacity */
    this.opacity = opacity;
    if (pJS.particles.opacity.anim.enable) {
      this.opacity_status = false;
      this.vo = pJS.particles.opacity.anim.speed / 100;
      if (!pJS.particles.opacity.anim.sync) {
        this.vo = this.vo * Math.random();
      }
    }

    /* animation - velocity for speed */
    this.vx = -.5 + Math.random();
    this.vy = -.5 + Math.random();

  };

  pJS.fn.particle.prototype.draw = function() {

    pJS.canvas.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(' + this.color.r + ',' + this.color.g + ',' + this.color.b + ',' + this.opacity + ')';
    pJS.canvas.ctx.beginPath();

    switch (pJS.particles.shape) {
      case 'circle':
        pJS.canvas.ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
        break;

      case 'edge':
        pJS.canvas.ctx.rect(this.x, this.y, this.radius * 2, this.radius * 2);
        break;

      case 'triangle':
        pJS.canvas.ctx.moveTo(this.x, this.y - this.radius);
        pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(this.x + this.radius, this.y + this.radius);
        pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(this.x - this.radius, this.y + this.radius);
        pJS.canvas.ctx.closePath();
        break;
    }

    pJS.canvas.ctx.fill();

  };

  pJS.fn.particlesCreate = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < pJS.particles.nb; i++) {
      pJS.particles.array.push(new pJS.fn.particle(pJS.particles.color_rgb, pJS.particles.opacity.opacity));
    }
  };

  pJS.fn.particlesAnimate = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < pJS.particles.array.length; i++) {
      /* the particle */
      var p = pJS.particles.array[i];

      /* move the particle */
      p.x += p.vx * (pJS.particles.anim.speed / 2);
      p.y += p.vy * (pJS.particles.anim.speed / 2);

      /* change opacity status */
      if (pJS.particles.opacity.anim.enable) {
        if (p.opacity_status == true) {
          if (p.opacity >= pJS.particles.opacity.opacity) p.opacity_status = false;
          p.opacity += p.vo;
        } else {
          if (p.opacity <= pJS.particles.opacity.anim.opacity_min) p.opacity_status = true;
          p.opacity -= p.vo;
        }
      }

      /* change particle position if it is out of canvas */
      switch (pJS.interactivity.events.onresize.mode) {
        case 'bounce':
          if (p.x - p.radius > pJS.canvas.w) p.vx = -p.vx;
          else if (p.x + p.radius < 0) p.vx = -p.vx;
          if (p.y - p.radius > pJS.canvas.h) p.vy = -p.vy;
          else if (p.y + p.radius < 0) p.vy = -p.vy;
          break;

        case 'out':
          if (p.x - p.radius > pJS.canvas.w) p.x = p.radius;
          else if (p.x + p.radius < 0) p.x = pJS.canvas.w + p.radius;
          if (p.y - p.radius > pJS.canvas.h) p.y = p.radius;
          else if (p.y + p.radius < 0) p.y = pJS.canvas.h + p.radius;
          break;
      }


      /* Check distance between each particle and mouse position */
      for (var j = i + 1; j < pJS.particles.array.length; j++) {
        var p2 = pJS.particles.array[j];

        /* link particles if enable */
        if (pJS.particles.line_linked.enable_auto) {
          pJS.fn.vendors.distanceParticles(p, p2);
        }

        /* set interactivity if enable */
        if (pJS.interactivity.enable) {

          /* interactivity mode */
          switch (pJS.interactivity.mode) {
            case 'grab':
              pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.grabParticles(p, p2);
              break;
          }

        }


      }
    }
  };

  pJS.fn.particlesDraw = function() {
    /* clear canvas */
    pJS.canvas.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, pJS.canvas.w, pJS.canvas.h);

    /* move particles */
    pJS.fn.particlesAnimate();

    /* draw each particle */
    for (var i = 0; i < pJS.particles.array.length; i++) {
      var p = pJS.particles.array[i];
      p.draw('rgba(' + p.color.r + ',' + p.color.g + ',' + p.color.b + ',' + p.opacity + ')');
    }

  };

  pJS.fn.particlesRemove = function() {
    pJS.particles.array = [];
  };


  /* ---------- VENDORS functions ------------ */

  pJS.fn.vendors.distanceParticles = function(p1, p2) {

    var dx = p1.x - p2.x,
      dy = p1.y - p2.y,
      dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    /* Check distance between particle and mouse mos */
    if (dist <= pJS.particles.line_linked.distance) {

      /* draw the line */
      var color_line = pJS.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line;
      pJS.canvas.ctx.beginPath();
      pJS.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + color_line.r + ',' + color_line.g + ',' + color_line.b + ',' + (pJS.particles.line_linked.opacity - dist / pJS.particles.line_linked.distance) + ')';
      pJS.canvas.ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
      pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(p2.x, p2.y);
      pJS.canvas.ctx.lineWidth = pJS.particles.line_linked.width;
      pJS.canvas.ctx.stroke();
      pJS.canvas.ctx.closePath();

      /* condensed particles */
      if (pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.enable) {
        var dx = p1.x - p2.x,
          dy = p1.y - p2.y,
          ax = dx / (pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateX * 1000),
          ay = dy / (pJS.particles.line_linked.condensed_mode.rotateY * 1000);
        p2.vx += ax;
        p2.vy += ay;
      }

    }

  };

  pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.listeners = function() {

    /* init el */
    if (pJS.interactivity.detect_on == 'window') {
      var detect_el = window;
    } else {
      var detect_el = pJS.canvas.el;
    }

    /* el on mousemove */
    detect_el.onmousemove = function(e) {

      if (detect_el == window) {
        var pos_x = e.clientX,
          pos_y = e.clientY;
      } else {
        var pos_x = e.offsetX || e.clientX,
          pos_y = e.offsetY || e.clientY;
      }

      if (pJS) {

        pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x = pos_x;
        pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y = pos_y;

        if (pJS.retina) {
          pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x *= pJS.canvas.pxratio;
          pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y *= pJS.canvas.pxratio;
        }

        pJS.interactivity.status = 'mousemove';
      }

    };

    /* el on onmouseleave */
    detect_el.onmouseleave = function(e) {

      if (pJS) {
        pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x = 0;
        pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y = 0;
        pJS.interactivity.status = 'mouseleave';
      }

    };

    /* el on onclick */
    if (pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.enable) {
      switch (pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.mode) {
        case 'push':
          detect_el.onclick = function(e) {
            pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.pushParticles(pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.nb, pJS.interactivity.mouse);
          }
          break;

        case 'remove':
          detect_el.onclick = function(e) {
            pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.removeParticles(pJS.interactivity.events.onclick.nb);
          }
          break;
      }
    }
  };

  pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.pushParticles = function(nb, pos) {
    if (pJS) {
      for (var i = 0; i < nb; i++) {
        pJS.particles.array.push(
          new pJS.fn.particle(
            pJS.particles.color_rgb,
            pJS.particles.opacity.opacity, {
              'x': pos ? pos.pos_x : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.w,
              'y': pos ? pos.pos_y : Math.random() * pJS.canvas.h
            }
          )
        )
      }
    }
  };

  pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.removeParticles = function(nb) {
    if (pJS) {
      pJS.particles.array.splice(0, nb);
    }
  };


  pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.grabParticles = function(p1, p2) {
    var dx = p1.x - p2.x,
      dy = p1.y - p2.y,
      dist = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);

    var dx_mouse = p1.x - pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x,
      dy_mouse = p1.y - pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y,
      dist_mouse = Math.sqrt(dx_mouse * dx_mouse + dy_mouse * dy_mouse);

    /* Check distance between 2 particles + Check distance between 1 particle and mouse position */
    if (dist <= pJS.particles.line_linked.distance && dist_mouse <= pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance && pJS.interactivity.status == 'mousemove') {
      /* Draw the line */
      var color_line = pJS.particles.line_linked.color_rgb_line;
      pJS.canvas.ctx.beginPath();
      pJS.canvas.ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(' + color_line.r + ',' + color_line.g + ',' + color_line.b + ',' + (pJS.interactivity.line_linked.opacity - dist_mouse / pJS.interactivity.mouse.distance) + ')';
      pJS.canvas.ctx.moveTo(p1.x, p1.y);
      pJS.canvas.ctx.lineTo(pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_x, pJS.interactivity.mouse.pos_y);
      pJS.canvas.ctx.lineWidth = pJS.particles.line_linked.width;
      pJS.canvas.ctx.stroke();
      pJS.canvas.ctx.closePath();
    }
  };

  pJS.fn.vendors.destroy = function() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(pJS.fn.requestAnimFrame);
    canvas_el.remove();
    pJS = null;
  };


  /* --------- LAUNCH ----------- */

  function launchParticles() {
    pJS.fn.canvasInit();
    pJS.fn.canvasSize();
    pJS.fn.canvasPaint();
    pJS.fn.particlesCreate();
    pJS.fn.particlesDraw();
    pJS.fn.densityAuto();
  };


  function launchAnimation() {
    pJS.fn.particlesDraw();
    pJS.fn.requestAnimFrame = requestAnimFrame(launchAnimation);
  };


  launchParticles();

  if (pJS.particles.anim.enable) {
    launchAnimation();
  }

  if (pJS.interactivity.enable) {
    pJS.fn.vendors.interactivity.listeners();
  }


};

/* --- VENDORS --- */

window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.requestAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msRequestAnimationFrame ||
    function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
})();

window.cancelRequestAnimFrame = (function() {
  return window.cancelAnimationFrame ||
    window.webkitCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.mozCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.oCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
    window.msCancelRequestAnimationFrame ||
    clearTimeout
})();

function hexToRgb(hex) {
  // By Tim Down - http://stackoverflow.com/a/5624139/3493650
  // Expand shorthand form (e.g. "03F") to full form (e.g. "0033FF")
  var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
  hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function(m, r, g, b) {
    return r + r + g + g + b + b;
  });
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)
  } : null;
};


/* --- LAUNCH --- */

window.particlesJS = function(tag_id, params) {

  /* no string id? so it's object params, and set the id with default id */
  if (typeof(tag_id) != 'string') {
    params = tag_id;
    tag_id = 'particles-js';
  }

  /* no id? set the id to default id */
  if (!tag_id) {
    tag_id = 'particles-js';
  }

  /* create canvas element */
  var canvas_el = document.createElement('canvas');

  /* set size canvas */
  canvas_el.style.width = "100%";
  canvas_el.style.height = "100%";

  /* append canvas */
  var canvas = document.getElementById(tag_id).appendChild(canvas_el);

  /* launch particle.js */
  if (canvas != null) {
    launchParticlesJS(tag_id, params);
  }

};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='particles-js'></div>
```

Comment: Не пробовали window.particlesJS ?

Comment: Код, приведенный в вопросе, работает.